# iOS app fails to build in fastlane but works in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm building a React Native app and am using Fastlane to manage my signing, building and deployment. I'm trying to build an ad-hoc package but each time I run the build using Fastlane `gym`, I get an error message about a missing header file. The build runs fine in Xcode from Product -> Build and I can run the app fine in my local simulators.

The error message I'm seeing is from `gym` `AppDelegate.m:13:9: 'ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h' file not found`, which I'm aware is associated with the [React Native Navigation setup](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing), and have followed the steps to fix it.

Has anyone seen this error before, or have any suggestions on how to get more information about why the Xcode build is working? I've tried scrubbing my `build`, `pods` and `node_modules` directories with no luck. I'm using React Native 0.59.9 and Xcode 11.3.1.

This is what I have in my `Fastfile`:

```
match(
  type: "adhoc",
  git_branch: "master",
  git_url: "<my cert repo>",
  app_identifier: ["<main app ID>", "<app extension ID"],
  team_id: "<my team ID>",
  readonly: true,
)
sh('yarn', 'build:ios')
gym(
  workspace: "myApp.xcworkspace",
  scheme: "myApp",
  configuration: "Beta",
  export_method: 'ad-hoc',
  output_directory: "builds",
  output_name: ipaName,
)
```

FYI, in this case `yarn build:ios` is an alias for `react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios --platform ios`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call yarn build:ios. gym should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

***Azure DevOps CICD setup; here is complete solution***
Note: ENV['variable'] are variables configured on Azure DevOps pipeline

1. Add to Apple

   ```
   app_identifier("app.bundle.name") # The bundle identifier of your app
   ```
2. put code in Gymfile

   ```
    scheme("ProjectSchemeName")
    export_options({
                   method: "app-store",
                   provisioningProfiles: { 
                   "app.bundle.name" =>  "Distribution-ProvisioningProfileName",
                      }
                  })

     # Specify the path to store .ipa file
     output_directory("./fastlane/builds")
     # Excludes bitcode from the build
     include_bitcode(false)
     # Excludes symbols from the build.
     include_symbols(false)
   ```
3. add to Deliverfile

   ```
   # Indicates that it’s a free app.
   price_tier(0)
   # Answer the questions Apple would present to you upon manually submitting for review
   submission_information({
          export_compliance_compliance_required: false,
          export_compliance_encryption_updated: false,
          export_compliance_uses_encryption: false,
          content_rights_contains_third_party_content: false,
          add_id_info_uses_idfa: false,
          export_compliance_contains_third_party_cryptography: false,
          export_compliance_contains_proprietary_cryptography: false,
          content_rights_contains_third_party_content: false
        })

   # Contact information for the app review team.
   app_review_information(
          first_name: "Name",
          last_name: "Name",
          phone_number: "4324234324",
          email_address: "example@gmail.com",
          demo_user: "test@app.com",
          demo_password: "Password",
          notes: "This mobile application requires subscription."
    )

    automatic_release(false)

    reset_ratings(false)

    app_rating_config_path("./fastlane/metadata/app_store_rating_config.json")

    copyright("© 2022 organisation")

    primary_category("Business")
   ```
4. update Fastfile to

   ```
    default_platform(:ios)

    platform :ios do

    desc "Description of what the lane does"
    lane :authenticate_app_stoe do

     #  APP STORE AUTHENTICATION USING API KEY
    app_store_connect_api_key(
         key_id: ENV['KEY_ID'],
         issuer_id: ENV['ISSUER_ID'],
         key_content: ENV['KEY_CONTENT'],
         is_key_content_base64: true,
         in_house: false
        )
    end

    # FASTLANE SYNC TO USE CERTIFICATES ON LOCAL MACHINE RATHER THAN CREATING NEW ONE.  
    desc "Sync certificates"
    lane :sync_certificates do
        #read-only disables match from overriding the existing certificates.
        match({readonly: true, type: "appstore"})
    end

    lane :set_build_number do 
         authenticate_app_store
         increment_version_number(version_number: ENV['APP_VERSION'])
         increment_build_number({ build_number: latest_testflight_build_number(version: ENV['APP_VERSION'], app_identifier: 'app.bundle.name') + 1 }) 
    end

    lane :deliver_metadata do
         authenticate_app_store
         deliver(
                 skip_binary_upload: true,
                 username: ENV['USERNAME'], #'example@gmail.com',
                 precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
                 automatic_release: false,
                 skip_app_version_update: false,
                 skip_screenshots: true,
                 force: true
               )
    end

    # LANE TO UPLOAD BUILD ON TESTFLIGHT
    desc "Create ipa"
    lane :beta_release do
         build
         upload_to_testflight()
    end


    desc "Create ipa"
    lane :build do
         set_build_number
         build_app
    end

    # LATE FOR BETA BUILD DEPLOYMENT
    desc "Create ipa"
    lane :release do
         build
         deliver_metadata
    end

    end
   ```
5. app_store_rating_config.json example

   ```
    {
    "CARTOON_FANTASY_VIOLENCE": 0,
    "REALISTIC_VIOLENCE": 0,
    "PROLONGED_GRAPHIC_SADISTIC_REALISTIC_VIOLENCE": 0,
    "PROFANITY_CRUDE_HUMOR": 0,
    "MATURE_SUGGESTIVE": 0,
    "HORROR": 0,
    "MEDICAL_TREATMENT_INFO": 0,
    "ALCOHOL_TOBACCO_DRUGS": 0,
    "GAMBLING": 0,
    "SEXUAL_CONTENT_NUDITY": 0,
    "GRAPHIC_SEXUAL_CONTENT_NUDITY": 0,
    "UNRESTRICTED_WEB_ACCESS": 0,
    "GAMBLING_CONTESTS": 0
   }
   ```