# Fastlane error: Could not find a version to edit for app for 'IOS'

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

In my Flutter app, I want to send the screenshots of my app using Fastlane.

I already managed to achieve that for the Android version, but I'm struggling with the iOS version.

So here is what I did so far:

```
cd ios

# I had to use sudo for some reason:
sudo fastlane init

# I managed to get all my current screenshots and metadata locally:
sudo fastlane deliver init --use_live_version true

# Now using the 'screenshots' lane (see below), I try to upload my screenshots:
sudo fastlane screenshots
```

Here is my `screenshots` lane:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Send screenshots to App Store Connect"
  lane :screenshots do
    deliver(
      submit_for_review: true,
      skip_binary_upload: true,
      skip_metadata: true,
      skip_app_version_update: true,
      skip_screenshots: false,
      overwrite_screenshots: true,
      screenshots_path: "./screenshots",
      force: true,
      app_version: "1.5.3"
    )
  end
end
```

And here is my `Deliverfile`:

```
api_key_path "./app_store_connect.json"
use_live_version true
```

But when I run that lane, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version to edit for app 'Mistikee Lite' for 'IOS'
```

How can I fix that so I can upload my screenshots?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is complete [Fastlane setup for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455467/4781814) solution that may help you!

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because my app was already approved and in production.

Comment: But your pipleine should support to upload builds to support next new version. Here is solution that may help if someone still looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455467/4781814

Answer (score 0):

to create new version add flag `--app_version $(new_version)`

(you cannot update version which is already released)