# Testflight: Failing to deploy React native app using fastlane xcode 14

Tags: react-native, jenkins, testflight, fastlane, xcode14

I am using xcode 14 and fastlane 2.211. Working with react native 0.67

while deploying the test version to the testflight with Jenkins, the following error pops up.

`fatal error: module 'yoga' in AST file '**.pcm' (imported by AST file '/**.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load Yoga.modulemap'?`

How can I fix my builds?

Answer (score 0):

**I am working with Xcode 14.3 and following pod file configuration works for me. try to match it if you could**

```
config = use_native_modules!

use_react_native!(:path => config[:reactNativePath])

target 'ProjectTests' do
  inherit! :complete
end

use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.95.0' })
IOS_VERSION = '12.0'

post_install do |installer|

    flipper_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = IOS_VERSION
            end
      
            case target.name
            when 'RCT-Folly'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
              end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Check my answer for [complete fastlane setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455467/4781814) on devOps pipeline**