# Increment build number with fastlane without changing project file?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-gym

I am setting up fastlane to run the builds of our iOS app. Is there a way to increment the build number based on the latest TestFlight build and upload a build, but without changing the project file? I'd rather not pollute the Git history with build number changes. Currently the app is being built with Xcode Cloud and somehow it's managing to keep `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 1` in the project file.

Unless I'm missing something I would basically have to do:

```
    current_version = get_version_number()
    previous_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
      api_key: api_key,
      app_identifier: app_identifier,
      version: current_version
    )
    
    current_build_number = previous_build_number + 1
    
    increment_build_number(
      build_number: current_build_number
    )
    
    build_ios_app(...)
    
    increment_build_number(
      build_number: 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if following fastlanes code helps for you

1. get yourself authenticated with Apple Store

   ```
   lane :authenticate_app_store do
     app_store_connect_api_key(
            key_id: ENV['KEY_ID'],
            issuer_id: ENV['ISSUER_ID'],
            key_content: ENV['KEY_CONTENT'],
            is_key_content_base64: true,
            in_house: false
     )
   end
   ```
2. Update your build number

   ```
    lane :set_build_number do 
          authenticate_app_store
          increment_version_number(version_number: ENV['APP_VERSION'])
          increment_build_number({ build_number: latest_testflight_build_number(version: ENV['APP_VERSION'], app_identifier: 'com.retaininternational.phoenixmobile') + 1 })
    end
   ```

**Check for [complete fastlane setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455467/4781814)**

Comment: But doesn't `increment_build_number` update the Xcode project file? This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Hey @andrei, to generate build with updated build number definetly we need to update in Xcode file. Also, on CI it does changes on copy of source repo. It doesn't make change permanently on original repo.